# jQuery append nested elements in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

I want to append elements using jQuery. For all browsers except IE8 the following line works:

```
  $("#myContainer").append('<button type="button" id="myButton"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></button>');
```

In IE8 only the outer button element is created.

If I instead split the append line into two lines it works in IE8 as well as all other browsers:

```
  $("#myContainer").append('<button type="button" id="myButton"></button>');      
  $("#myButton").append('<i class="fa fa-home"></i>');
```

Is there some way I can make the first line work for IE8 as well?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 1.11.1

Comment: I was just wondering if it was v2.x, which works just from IE 9.

Comment: try this:-http://jsfiddle.net/asdasdasdas/shE58/28/

Comment: jsFiddle doesn't shake hands with IE 8.

Comment: @MelanciaUK yes i haven't test actually but should work

Comment: Unless you use http://jsfiddle.net/draft/

Comment: The code you put in the jsFiddle is exactly the same as the second part of the question, which the OP already says it's working. You just called `.append()` in a chain.

Comment: yes somewhat but there is no need to select element again by id

Comment: The problem seems to occur because I'm including another javascript with a collection of polyfills for IE8   (https://github.com/WebReflection/ie8). When I remove this javascript file the appending works correctly.